# SnapKit fails return to app after logging into Snapchat

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I have been trying to direct Snapchat back to my app after authenticating on Snapchat to no success. Here is the code I have in my app delegate which is where I think it is not working:

```
import UIKit
import SCSDKLoginKit


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  
    func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL,
                     options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return SCSDKLoginClient.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }
  @available (iOS 13, *)
   func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
       for urlContext in URLContexts {
           let options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [
               .openInPlace: urlContext.options.openInPlace,
               .sourceApplication: urlContext.options.sourceApplication!,
               .annotation: urlContext.options.annotation!
           ]
    SCSDKLoginClient.application(UIApplication.shared, open: urlContext.url, options: options)
       }
}
```

I have set up a URL Scheme and a Redirect URL in SnapKitDevPortal. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE: SOLUTION FOUND**
First, I had to implement this bit of code in the SceneDelegate if using iOS 13:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
     for urlContext in URLContexts {
         let url = urlContext.url
         var options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
         options[.openInPlace] = urlContext.options.openInPlace
         options[.sourceApplication] = urlContext.options.sourceApplication
         options[.annotation] = urlContext.options.annotation
         SCSDKLoginClient.application(UIApplication.shared, open: url, options: options)
     }
 }
```

Then, I found the simple mistake that I made while setting up my info.plist. In Snapchat's documentation, under "CFBundleURLSchemes", it says that this should contain the value "myapp". I did not understand that this was referring to the URL Scheme, and not the name of the app. So if your app name was "mycoolapp" and your URL Scheme was "myapp://snapauth", then you would put "myapp" under "CFLBundleURLSchemes", *not* "mycoolapp". Hope this helps.

Comment: Well I have checked multiple times my CFLBundleURLSchemes is okay everything is ok when I put data in demo app but whenI copy paste same data in my app it won't redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Since you already have the implementation for `openURL` in `AppDelegate` you just need to call it from `SceneDelegate`, like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
        return
    }
    let _ = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
        UIApplication.shared,
        open: url,
        sourceApplication: nil,
        annotation: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])        
}
```

You need to add the url scheme you want your app to open in the info.plist file under the `<array>` of `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`, like this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>snapchat</string>
<array>
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. In LSApplicationQueriesSchemes I already have  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>myURLScheme</string>
  <string>itms-apps</string>
  <string>bitmoji-sdk</string>
  <string>snapchat</string>
 </array>

Comment: Did you check the sample app that they have provided on [Github](https://github.com/Snapchat/login-kit-sample). Maybe, it's something minor that you're missing.

Comment: I have and the same problem occurs on the demo app as well. I've looked through it pretty thoroughly. My only guess is that it has something to do with the AppDelegate as I had to change it slightly due to iOS 13 and scenes. When attempting to return to my app, Safari says it can't because the address is invalid.

Comment: I've updated the implementation required for `openURLContexts`. Check to see if it works.

Comment: I've called `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
       for urlContext in URLContexts {
           let options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [
               .openInPlace: urlContext.options.openInPlace,
               .sourceApplication: urlContext.options.sourceApplication!,
               .annotation: urlContext.options.annotation!
           ]
    SCSDKLoginClient.application(UIApplication.shared, open: urlContext.url, options: options)
       }
}` from the Scene Delegate and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution Swift version 5.6.1

Add these lines into `info.plist`

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.example.myApp</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>myApp</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>snapchat</string>
        <string>bitmoji-sdk</string>
        <string>itms-apps</string>
    </array>
    <key>SCSDKClientId</key>
    <string><YOUR CLIENT ID></string>
    <key>SCSDKRedirectUrl</key>
    <string><YOUR REDIRECT URL></string>
    <key>SCSDKScopes</key>
    <array>
        <string>https://auth.snapchat.com/oauth2/api/user.display_name</string>
        <string>https://auth.snapchat.com/oauth2/api/user.external_id</string>
        <string>https://auth.snapchat.com/oauth2/api/user.bitmoji.avatar</string>
    </array>
```

and then add this function in `AppDelegate.swift`

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return SCSDKLoginClient.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }
```

and finally this function in `SceneDelegate.swift`

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        for urlContext in URLContexts {
                 let url = urlContext.url
                 var options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
                 options[.openInPlace] = urlContext.options.openInPlace
                 options[.sourceApplication] = urlContext.options.sourceApplication
                 options[.annotation] = urlContext.options.annotation
                 SCSDKLoginClient.application(UIApplication.shared, open: url, options: options)
        }
    }
```

and you are good to go