# Snapchat Login Kit is unable to redirect to my app

Tags: ios, swift, snapchat

I try to use Snapchat's Login Kit. But it doesn't redirect to my app after authentication.

I used this Login Kit before which is still working now. So I also compared both info.plist which are identical except for "SCSDKClientId", "SCSDKRedirectUrl" and "CFBundleURLSchemes"

Here's my info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>MY_APP_NAME</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>SCSDKClientId</key>
    <string>MY_SCSDK_CLIENT_ID</string>
    <key>SCSDKRedirectUrl</key>
    <string>MY_APP_NAME://snap-kit/oauth2</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>itms-apps</string>
        <string>snapchat</string>
        <string>bitmoji-sdk</string>
    </array>
    <key>SCSDKScopes</key>
    <array>
        <string>https://auth.snapchat.com/oauth2/api/user.bitmoji.avatar</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I make sure that the SCSDKRedirectUrl is the same as the developer portal one

The following function gets called.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        if SCSDKLoginClient.application(app, open: url, options: options) {return true}
        
        return false
}
```

But `SCSDKLoginClient.application(app, open: url, options: options)` returns `false` all the time.

I'm out of ideas why this happens now. Any thoughts will be appreciated.

**Update**: I missed the `SceneDelegate` part for ios13. The solution can be find here: [SnapKit fails return to app after logging into Snapchat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62269404/snapkit-fails-return-to-app-after-logging-into-snapchat)

Comment: facing the same issue....did you found the solution? @Yao

Comment: @UdayBabariya No, unfortunately. I didn't have enough time to research on this. This issue was so weired

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this problem for some time now and I wish that the Snap Kit Documentation would provide more insight on this. Essentially, you may have not set up your URL Schemes. This actually isn't a Snap Chat problem but a p.list problem. You can check if your app allows redirects using safari. Here is the article I read, good luck!
https://kitefaster.com/2016/07/13/how-to-open-ios-app-with-custom-url/